# How to make Smart Icon Animations (when Launch and Exit Apps) in Android?

Tags: android, appicon

`Smart Animated Icons` is one of the Highlighted Features of `MIUI 9`.You can see the New Animation when you Launch and Exit Apps. Open/Launch the App and You can notice the Animation on its Icon when you exit the App. Animation seems to be cool and it gives you a live Experience as if Icons are Live. Take a look at the below GIFs to see the Animation on Icons.

Facebook Smart Icon animation exmaple.

[image]

Settings app Smart Icon animation

[image]

For more smart App icon Animation understanding and information please check this link [Smart Icon Animation](http://c.mi.com/thread-481744-1-1.html)

1) how to achieve this same features ? How can I do it in my app?

2) Android SDK that supports dynamic app icons ? is it possible to achieve this using `<activity-alias>` ?

Comment: Hi Sagar, did you find anything?

Comment: nope @SudipPodder,

Answer (score 6):

Yes, these are Smart Icon animations introduced in MIUI 9. MIUI does the icon animation by itself upon enabling it from system settings as mentioned here on [Xiomi MIUI Offical forum](http://en.miui.com/thread-720973-1-1.html).

It happens only for some system apps and some famous social media platforms as of now, may happen for other famous app icons in the future too. But as they mentioned in the link, it is a part of the MIUI 9.0, and is not part of Android SDK.

I too wish they include this feature as part of Android SDK to be shipped with the application. It would be intriguing.